# TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments in python

Tags: python

How do i print e1 and e2 values. it does not return any values.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self,name,age):
       self.name=name
       self.age=age

       e1=Employee("xyz",'25')
       e2=Employee("abc",'23')
       print("Employee Details...")

       print("Name:",e1.name,"age:",e1.age)
       print("Name:",e2.name,"age:",e2.age)
       return
t=Employee()
print t
```

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do? What are you getting (Error or unexpected result?) ?

Comment: @AnandSKumar, i think, you have edited by solving the issue the code had. Wrong edit

Comment: @AhsanulHaque No, I haven't I just included `class Employee:` line, which was not inside the code block, into the code block. The above program as it is, does not run for sure. It is trying to create `Employee()` , but `Employee()`'s `__init__()` takes 2 more arguments.

Comment: That's because of no parameter is passed.  I don't know who edited it, but certainly `__init__` is not there. function name was `fun`

Comment: i want to print e1 and e2 how do i call?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque The op changed it from` fun()` to `__init__()` .

Comment: e1,e2 are class objects. What is the benifit of printing them?

Comment: `t=Employee()` tries to create an `Employee` object without a `name` or `age`.

Comment: The code is a little bit messy. Is the indentation wrong or are you trying to create an instance of the class within the constructor. Then `__init__` doesn't need `return`.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque: You can see the revision history by clicking on the blue [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32944471/revisions) text above the avatar of the last editor. In this case, the original text _was_ (inappropriately) modified by Vignesh Kalai, but he happened to guess well, and his edit was then improved by the OP. Anand S Kumar's edit was fine, it simply included the `class Employee:` line into the code block.

Comment: I want Output like below . thanks in advance

Employee Details:
(' Name:', 'xyz',  'age:'25')
(' Name:', 'abc', 'age:'23')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do seems like reinventing the `__str__` method. Here is a suggestion how you could do that:

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return "Name: {0}, age: {1}".format(self.name, self.age)


t = Employee("uday", 25)
print t
```

I am making here some assumptions and am trying to guess your actual goal.
I hope that it still helps.

Comment: `__repr__` is the right method to override for printing object in user readable form.

Comment: @ozgur Take a look here please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python. It says `__str__` is okay for printing human readable output. `__repr__` should rather provide a unique output. Depending on the goals of the OP, maybe `__repr__` would fit better, but as said I'm just making some assumptions and therefore my answer is based on them.

Comment: @cezar: I agree that your `__str__` definition is appropriate. However, as the accepted answer on the page you linked says: "almost every object you implement should have a functional `__repr__` that’s usable for understanding the object. Implementing `__str__` is optional: do that if you need a “pretty print” functionality".

Comment: Let's not get into an extended discussion of this topic here. If you _do_ want to discuss it, please feel free to do so in [the SO Python Chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm just assuming the OP wants pretty print. His question is: how do I print e1 and e2. Otherwise the objection about using `__repr__` is absolutely correct. The intention of the answer is to point out a better (pythonic) way of printing object values.

Answer (score 1):

You should redefine `__init__` method. That's because `__init__` is called while object initialization.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age=age

e1=Employee("xyz",'25')
e2=Employee("abc",'23')
print("Employee Details...")

print("Name:",e1.name,"age:",e1.age)
print("Name:",e2.name,"age:",e2.age)
```

Edit:

You can use this code to achieve your desired output with a little update.

You can add commas `,` after `print` to allow next `print` statement start at the same line , change the code like that:

```
    class Employee:

    def __init__(self, name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age=age

e1=Employee("xyz",'25')
e2=Employee("abc",'23')
print("Employee Details:"),

print("Name:",e1.name,"age:",e1.age),
print("Name:",e2.name,"age:",e2.age)
```

Output:

```
Employee Details: (' Name:', 'xyz', 'age:'25') (' Name:', 'abc', 'age:'23')
```

Comment: This is probably what the OP is actually trying to do.